# JBoss 6.4 classloading

Tags: hibernate, jboss, classloading

I have an .ear which contains multiples .war and I would like to deploy it into a jboss 6.4.7 server. The problem is that one of the .war is using a jboss's module (hibernate-jpa-2.0) but the app requires the hibernate-jpa-2.1 version. How to tell my war not using this jboss module. I have added a jboss-deployment-structure into the Ear/application/META-INF with this exclusion :

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>

<sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.persistence.api" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

but not working..

The "javax.persistence.api" is written on the module.xml on the jboss server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="jpa" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="javaee.api" />
    </exclusions>
        </sub-deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

> A subsystem is the set of capabilities added by an extension.It
>   defines how it will be used and configured. It is also defined in the
>   EAP configuration file (standalone.xml or domain.xml) using the
>    tag under a profile. 
>   For every extension added in an EAP instance, the  capabilities and attributes of that extension are
>   configured with the `<subsystem>` element.

Another option can be just replace jar in the JBOSS with newer one

Comment: Thanks dude it's working. But where did you find the <subsystem name="jpa" /> ? where can I find it ? i would like to do the same thing for jboss logging and SLF4J.  Thanks again.

Comment: Done. Thank you :)

Comment: I come here for the same problem but with jboss logging and slf4j. I have added in my jboss-deployments-structure this : <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
        <subsystem name="slf4j" />
    </exclude-subsystems> But the deployment failed with no error on the console. When I remove the <subsystem name="logging" /> it works but uses the jboss module (and I don't want that). What can I do ? Thanks

Comment: try to set SET "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j"

Comment: I have to use my application project only and not to modify in other location..  i have this on my console at the end : Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider and the deployment failed

Comment: @Freddy92 you should ask it as a new question. May be someone helps you)